# No module named pandas in conda command prompt

Tags: python, pandas, conda

I'm trying to run a script made on spyder that runs with no problem.

But when I try to run the same script it says Pandas is not installed.

But I checked on my conda env e seems to be already installed.

Why this happens?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem

You are using `pip` python's default package manager to install a package in python's default location.

But using Anaconda's virtual environment to run python script which requires packages to be installed in it's own directory via `conda` package maanger.

## Solution

Run this command in **Conda command pompt**:

```
conda install -c conda-forge pandas
```

Comment: Thank you. Is the same for all packages?

Comment: yes it's same for all packages and when you are using anaconda virtual environment (or the compiler) to run your project.